# fatal error: Array index out of range when trying to get to location

Tags: xcode, swift

I have an app where the user can add locations in different ways. 
One is by taping on the map and the other is taping a button to get their location.
All this is stored in a tableview and the user can press on the place in the tableView to get back to the place on the map.
The first part works great but when I try using the button , the place saves to the tableView (witch is perfect) but when I tap on it to get back to the saved place the app crashes and I get "fatal error: Array index out of range". I have been trying to find a solution for a while and still haven't found out how. Here is the code, let me know if you need more to help me out.

note that my my active places is not empty as this is what I get in my debug area:

```
activePlaces current value is 1
activePlaces current value is 1
activePlaces current value is (activePlaces)
activePlaces current value is -1
[<+37.33131185,-122.03075659> +/- 30.00m (speed 7.87 mps / course 176.86) @ 6/8/16, 6:54:38 PM Central European Summer Time]
[<+37.33131185,-122.03075659> +/- 30.00m (speed 7.87 mps / course 176.86) @ 6/8/16, 6:54:38 PM Central European Summer Time]
[<+37.33131185,-122.03075659> +/- 30.00m (speed 7.87 mps / course 176.86) @ 6/8/16, 6:54:38 PM Central European Summer Time]
[<+37.33115792,-122.03076853> +/- 30.00m (speed 8.33 mps / course 178.34) @ 6/8/16, 6:54:38 PM Central European Summer Time]
[<+37.33115792,-122.03076853> +/- 30.00m (speed 8.33 mps / course 178.34) @ 6/8/16, 6:54:38 PM Central European Summer Time]
[<+37.33107980,-122.03077250> +/- 30.00m (speed 8.20 mps / course 177.87) @ 6/8/16, 6:54:39 PM Central European Summer Time]
[<+37.33100231,-122.03077622> +/- 30.00m (speed 8.20 mps / course 178.34) @ 6/8/16, 6:54:40 PM Central European Summer Time]
[<+37.33092521,-122.03077056> +/- 10.00m (speed 8.34 mps / course 173.92) @ 6/8/16, 6:54:41 PM Central European Summer Time]
[<+37.33085898,-122.03075862> +/- 10.00m (speed 7.23 mps / course 170.25) @ 6/8/16, 6:54:42 PM Central European Summer Time]
[<+37.33079800,-122.03072881> +/- 10.00m (speed 7.11 mps / course 157.66) @ 6/8/16, 6:54:43 PM Central European Summer Time]
[<+37.33074557,-122.03069850> +/- 10.00m (speed 6.29 mps / course 155.33) @ 6/8/16, 6:54:44 PM Central European Summer Time]
[<+37.33069642,-122.03066881> +/- 10.00m (speed 5.94 mps / course 156.32) @ 6/8/16, 6:54:45 PM Central European Summer Time]
[<+37.33065643,-122.03064682> +/- 10.00m (speed 4.77 mps / course 157.35) @ 6/8/16, 6:54:46 PM Central European Summer Time]
[<+37.33063636,-122.03063618> +/- 10.00m (speed 2.27 mps / course 158.84) @ 6/8/16, 6:54:47 PM Central European Summer Time]
[<+37.33061331,-122.03062365> +/- 10.00m (speed 1.90 mps / course 159.97) @ 6/8/16, 6:54:48 PM Central European Summer Time]
[<+37.33058184,-122.03060705> +/- 10.00m (speed 2.83 mps / course 160.58) @ 6/8/16, 6:54:49 PM Central European Summer Time]
activePlaces current value is 2
activePlaces current value is 2
fatal error: Index out of range
(lldb)
```

In the tableView:

```
var places = [Dictionary<String,String>()]

var activePlace = -1
```

---

```
   alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: { (action) -> Void in

        let lat = places[indexPath]["lat"]!

        let lon = places[indexPath]["lon"]!

        places.removeAtIndex(indexPath)

        places.insert(["name" : alert.textFields![0].text!, "lat" : lat, "lon" : lon], atIndex: indexPath)

        self.tableView.reloadData()

        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(places, forKey: "places")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

I also have this, still in the tableView

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> NSIndexPath? {

        activePlace = indexPath.row

        return indexPath

    }
```

in the ViewController

```
@IBAction func addCurentLoc(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    var newCoordinate2 = self.Map.userLocation.location!.coordinate;

    var location = CLLocation(latitude: newCoordinate2.latitude, longitude: newCoordinate2.longitude)

    //title = "new address"

    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation();
    annotation.title = title;
    annotation.coordinate = self.Map.userLocation.location!.coordinate;

    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(location) { (placemarks, error) -> Void in

        var title = ""

        if (error == nil) {

            if let p = placemarks?[0] {

                var subThouroughfare:String = ""
                var thouroughfare:String = ""

                if p.subThoroughfare != nil {

                    subThouroughfare = p.subThoroughfare!

                }

                if p.thoroughfare != nil {

                    thouroughfare = p.thoroughfare!

                }

                title = "\(subThouroughfare) \(thouroughfare)"

            }

        }

        if title == "" {

            title = "Added \(NSDate())"

        }

        places.append(["name":title,"lat":"\(newCoordinate2.latitude)","lon":"\(newCoordinate2.longitude)"])

        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()

        annotation.coordinate = newCoordinate2

        annotation.title = title

        self.Map.addAnnotation(annotation)

    }

    self.Map.addAnnotation(annotation);

    func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!,
        viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation!) -> MKAnnotationView!{
            if(annotation is MKUserLocation){
                return nil;
            }

            //   let pinView: Void = mapView.addAnnotation(annotation);
            let pinAnnotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation,reuseIdentifier:"MyIdentifier");
            return pinAnnotationView;

    }


    if activePlace == -1 {

        manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        manager.startUpdatingLocation()

    } else {
```

print("activePlaces current value is (activePlace)")

```
        let latitude = NSString(string: places[activePlace]["lat"]!).doubleValue

        let longitude = NSString(string: places[activePlace]["lon"]!).doubleValue

        let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)

        let latDelta:CLLocationDegrees = 0.01

        let lonDelta:CLLocationDegrees = 0.01

        let span:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(latDelta, lonDelta)

        let region:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(coordinate, span)

        self.Map.setRegion(region, animated: true)

        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()

        annotation.coordinate = coordinate


        annotation.title = places[activePlace]["name"]

        self.Map.addAnnotation(annotation)
    }
}
```

the error occurs on

let latitude = NSString(string: places[activePlace]["lat"]!).doubleValue

witch says "EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)"

Comment: On which line does the error occur?

Comment: @jtbandes the error occurs on

let latitude = NSString(string: places[activePlace]["lat"]!).doubleValue

witch says "EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)"    (I just updated the question)

Comment: Where are you setting `activePlace`. Also in your question you say the error happens when you tap the table view row, but the line `let latitude = NSString(string: places[activePlace]["lat"]!).doubleValue` occurs when you are adding a new place.

Comment: Are you serious to put a `MapKit` delegate method into a `IBAction` method?

Comment: @AlexPelletier Is this what you mean ?  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> NSIndexPath? {
        
        activePlace = indexPath.row
        
        return indexPath
        
    }
if so this is in the tableView

Comment: @vadian I haven't been coding for that long so I didn't know it was that bad, what should I change ?

Comment: Right now when you add a pin this is the order of operations:  press pin -> addCurentLoc: -> add new place to dictionary -> add annotation to map view . All of that is happening right after you press the plus icon. I think you are missing some closing brackets, but if not then you need restructure a bit.

Comment: Any delegate method must be located on the top level of the class, and `reverseGeocodeLocation` works asynchronously, that means the result in the closure is returned later after the method exits, so the method `self.Map.addAnnotation(annotation)` outside the block is useless.

Comment: Do you mean the entire problem is in the "addCurentLoc" action that needs to be restructured ? @vadian

Comment: Yes, consider the asynchronous behavior of `reverseGeocodeLocation` and process the returned data in the completion block